# How to revaluate done inventory in odoo 10.0

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am using odoo community version 10.0 edition

I have done opening stock for financial year april 2018
now today it seems some changes for some products related unit price so I want to update it

I have changed cost price from product form view and again generate report for opening stock of april 2018 by going to the following menu sequence

Inventory -> Inventory at date

But no effects

How can I do that ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Please ask such questions in the [official Odoo forums](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Comment: It requires Karma and I don't have karma friend

Comment: Then try to get Karma ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are in doing the periodic inventory valuation entry, Right? If yes then you may have to record entries before change the product qty to get accurate report.